# customer count where transactions are not null

Tags: sql

```
 with hrk as (
    select a.LBrCode,a.VcrAcctId,a.DrCr,a.FcyTrnAmt amt,
b.CustNo,b.AcctType,c.AMLRating x 
    from vcr a 
    inner join ac_mast b on a.LBrCode=b.LBrCode and substring(a.VcrAcctId,1,24)=substring(b.PrdAcctId,1,24)
    left join cust_mast c on b.CustNo=c.CustNo
    where a.entrydate  between '01-jan-2021' and '31-mar-2021'
)
select AcctType,
 count(*) over() cust_cnt,
sum(case when (DrCr='C' and x=1)then amt else 0 end) low_credit,
sum(case when (DrCr='C' and x=1)then 1 else 0 end)   low_credit_cnt,
sum(case when (DrCr='D' and x=1)then amt else 0 end) low_debit,
sum(case when (DrCr='D' and x=1)then 1 else 0 end)   low_debit_cnt,
                               
sum(case when (DrCr='C' and x=2)then amt else 0 end) Medium_credit,
sum(case when (DrCr='C' and x=2)then 1 else 0 end)   Medium_credit_cnt,
sum(case when (DrCr='D' and x=2)then amt else 0 end) Medium_debit,
sum(case when (DrCr='D' and x=2)then 1 else 0 end)   Medium_debit_cnt,
                               
sum(case when (DrCr='C' and x=2)then amt else 0 end) high_credit,
sum(case when (DrCr='C' and x=2)then 1 else 0 end)   high_credit_cnt,
sum(case when (DrCr='D' and x=2)then amt else 0 end) high_debit,
sum(case when (DrCr='D' and x=2)then 1 else 0 end)   high_debit_cnt
from hrk
group by AcctType
```

-- There can be N no of transactions for a given custNo and there can be multiple custono under AMLRating
I want No of Custno involved in each category namely low,medium,high where sum is not null

Comment: What DBMS are you using? This: `entrydate between '01-jan-2021' and '31-mar-2021'` is something you should not do. You are comparing a date with a string here, so the DBMS must convert the string to a date, which can fail depending on a session's region settings. Here is the same with a standard SQL date literal instead of a string literal: `entrydate between date '2021-01-01' and date '2021-03-31`.

Comment: This: `substring(a.VcrAcctId,1,24) = substring(b.PrdAcctId,1,24)` indicates an inappropriate data model. Normalization form NF1 requires columns to hold atomic values. If `substring(column,1,24)` has a meaning on its own, it should be a separate column.

Answer (score 1):

You have `count(*) over()` with the alias name `cust_cnt`. A better alias would be `acct_type_cnt`, because with the `OVER` clause you count how many rows are in your result, i.e. how many AcctType there are.

If you want to count customers, either use

```
count(*)
```

or use

```
count(custono)
```

if a customer number can be null

or use

```
count(distinct custono)
```

if a customer number can appear multiple times and you want to count it just once.

You can of course apply this on your conditional aggregation expressions, e.g.

```
count(distinct case when drcr = 'C' and x = 1 then custono end) low_credit_cnt,
```

Comment: thanks Mr Kettner   this is okay It is a solution thanks again